# What error is thrown if realm write fails due to low disk space

Tags: android, realm

We are trying to save each data of size 60-70MB in multiple realms. When there is low disk space we are good to delete one of the realm.

How to identify, that error thrown by realm is due to low disk space.

Trying to emulate low disk space. I got the below stacktrace.

```
W/System.err: Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. write(): failed: No space left on device in /Users/Nabil/Dev/realm/master/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:171)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:241)
W/System.err:     at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:231)
        at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:319)
        at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:282)
        at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:378)
```

Snippet to check:

```
try {
    // Insert data to realm
} catch (RealmError ex) {
    String detailMessage = ex.getMessage();

    if (detailMessage != null && detailMessage.contains("write()")
            && detailMessage.contains("No space left on device")) {

        // Time to delete old realm

    } else {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```